# cell color in a table -- add legend somewhere under the table to explain the meaning

Tags: tables, color, legend

```
\documentclass{article}  

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{a table}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c}
\cellcolor{blue!=10} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6  \\
4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I want to add a filled rectangle (color=blue!=10) somewhere under or next to the table (exact position does not matter) to explain the meaning of the cellcolor in the table. Basically, I want to create a legend.

Do I have to create a tikzpicture for that purpose or is there an easier workaround?

Comment: Just `\colorbox{blue!=10}{\strut\quad} explanation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table will look better by aligning the title and legend with the tabular. Add the `threeparttable` package and place the caption and the legend inside the `threeparttable` environment.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass{article}  

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{threeparttable}% added <<<<<<<<<<<
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \caption{A table}
            \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c}
                \cellcolor{blue!=10} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6  \\
                4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9  \\
            \end{tabular}           
            \fcolorbox{blue!30}{blue!10}{\small This cell is special}       
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

**OPTION**  To draw a small colored square use the command

`\legend[<optional color>]{<text>}`

[image: d]

```
\documentclass{article}  

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}  

\usepackage{threeparttable}% added <<<<<<<<<<<

\newcommand{\legend}[2][white]{%
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0.2pt}\fcolorbox{black}{#1}{\rule{0pt}{1.5ex}\rule{1.5ex}{0pt}}{\enspace \small #2}            
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \caption{A table}
            \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c}
                \cellcolor{blue!=10} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6  \\
                4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9  \\
            \end{tabular}           
        \legend[blue!10]{This cell is special}
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why did you put fcolorbox inside the threeparttable environment?

Comment: And: I also tried $\colorbox{blue!=10}{\strut\quad} this cell is special$ ins%tead of \fcolorbox{blue!30}{blue!10}{\small This cell is special} which, in contrast, causes two line breaks of "this cell is special". Why is that?

Comment: @Simon  The `threeparttable` package facilitates tables with caption and notes. The caption and
 notes are given a width equal to the body of the table (a tabular environment). Try a long caption or  legend to see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

With `tabularray`

```
\documentclass{article}  

\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document} 
  \begin{tblr}
      {
        colspec={*{6}{Q[c,mode=math]}},
        cell{1}{1}={bg=blue!10},
        cell{2}{3}={bg=red!10},
      }
      1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6  \\
      4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9
  \end{tblr} 
  \qquad
  \begin{tblr}
      {
        colspec={Q[wd=1em] Q},
        cell{1}{1}={bg=blue!10},
        cell{2}{1}={bg=red!10},
        vline{1,2},
        hline{1-Z} = {1}{solid},
      }
      & some text\\
      & another
  \end{tblr} 
\end{document}
```

[image]